# Using gparted before installing Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, gpt

I will be installing Windows 10 and Linux (dual-boot) on a new computer in a couple of days. I would like to use GPT instead of MBR for the partition table.

As I understand it (and have done in the past), it is much easier to install Windows first (and let it try to dominate the machine ) followed by the Linux install with grub allowing the dual boot.

Can I use the live USB stick with Linux to run `gparted` and create the GPT partition table, then boot Windows from its USB installer? Will Windows "respect" the partition table that I have created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest Windows can install automatically on GPT, and then proceed with Linux install as usual, modifying partitioning setup as required. Why would you partition first?

Comment: As I understand it, if I use the graphical "partition" manager during the Windows install (not `diskpart`), it will add an MBR partition even for a GPT table. Is that correct?

Comment: No, GPT is GPT. You will still have a "protective mbr" for backward compatibility, but that's a different story.
I'm assuming that your system is UEFI based and bootable media is in UEFI mode as well.

Comment: Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style

Comment: Thanks. The computer is a 2020 model (System76 desktop), so I **hope** is has UEFI. As far as the media goes, Linux is Pop OS that I wrote to a USB stick using the Ubuntu utility "Disk Image Writer". I'm not sure about the Windows one because I bought it from Microsoft (USB stick for installation), but I assume so.

Comment: UEFI/legacy mode depends on your BIOS(UEFI) settings, not on the device itself. Regards